# Music server (on premise) that allows editing playlists on all devices

Tags: music, server

Do you know a server software, where all my music can be mounted and I can access via Windows, Mac and Linux as well as mobile apps?

The most important thing for me is to edit all my playlists on all my devices when I filled the server storage with new music.

I would love to host the server as VM in ESXI; OS does not matter as soon the client apps are available on Windows, Mac, Linux, Android and iOS.

I would prefer not having a monthly billing or cloud. So on premise would be great and open source even better.

Comment: So you need 5 servers? :) I was suggesting you [edit] your initial post and add the details I mentioned – increases your chances to good answers matching your needs. To give you an idea (from what I guess you have and want): Going for UPnP/DLNA gives you the broadest support on all platforms. You most likely want MP3 and maybe OGG supported. The server runs on your Linux machine. Some examples for Android you can e.g. find in my listings on [DLNA / uPnP Server and Clients](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_dlna).

Comment: Hi Izzy, thank you I edited it. The most important feature would be my playlist editing on every device. Not 5 servers, but clients OS' ;-) Just looked at your list, what a great thing!

Comment: Thanks! And +1, now the Q looks complete :) I cannot speak for iOS/Mac and hardly for Windows, but as stated you should be on the safe side with UPnP/DLNA. [Kodi](http://kodi.tv/) might be a good choice, but could be a bit "oversized" (also does video incl. TV recording and more). While waiting for answers, you might wish to check with [these related and answered questions](/search?q=media-server+answers%3A1), e.g. [Free, easy, lightweight DLNA/UPnP servers for Linux](/q/402/185). Good luck!

Comment: Do you want to play the music on the server or on the client?

Comment: I would like to play only on client-side

Comment: Can you sync the playlists using DropBox or similar? Or mount a server drive on the devices and store the playlist on that?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/).

Support for [sharing music](https://nextcloud.com/sharing/) is just one of it features. Quote from this linked page:

> Share images, documents or music with colleagues on your server, send password protected public links to friends and get notifications on your phone when a user on another Nextcloud server shares files directly with you. Use Secure Drop to let customers upload files to you in a easy and secure way!

And it comes with all sorts of [Mobile and desktop clients](https://nextcloud.com/clients/). Quote from this linked page:

> - Nextcloud provides desktop clients for Windows, Mac and Linux ...
> - Nextcloud clients for Android and iOS allow you to sync and share your files, in a fully secure way through an encrypted connection.